# Image intervention wrong path al guardar imagen

Tags: laravel

resulta que siguiendo un tutorial para guardar la imagen hice esto

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {

        $file = Input::file('imagen1');
        $image = \Image::make(\Input::file('imagen1'));
        $path = public_path().'/thumbnails/';

        $image->save($path.$file->getClientOriginalName());
        $image->resize(null, 300, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->aspectRatio();
        });
        $image->save($path.'thumb_'.$file->getClientOriginalName());

        $thumbnail = new Thumbnail();
        $thumbnail->image = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $thumbnail->save();

        $request->user()->propiedades()->create($request->all());
        return redirect('profile#propiedades');
    }
```

Y mi problema es que me guarda el path de la ruta temporal y no la real, por lo cual cuando yo voy a mi tabla, nunca encuentra la imagen.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La imagen real esta guardada aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por lo cual mi pregunta es como hago para que guarde pero el path real asi cuando voy a mi blade puedo encontrar la imagen. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

No se si entiendo bien el codigo pero me parece que te falta moverlo al path. Te reciclo un codigo que use hace poquito.

```
if($request->file('imagen_1'))
    {
        //Manipulacion de imagenes
        $file= $request->file('imagen_1');
        $nombre= 'emap_1'.time().'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $path = public_path().'/img/articulos';
        $file->move($path,$nombre);

        $img = new Imagen(); 
        $img->nombre = $nombre;
        $img->descripcion = $request->descripcion_1;
        $img->articulo()->associate($articulo);
        $img->save();      
    }
```

En mi caso defino un nombre completo con la funcion time() para darle aleatoriedad al nombre. Defino mi path. Y con la funcion move() lo muevo.

Lo demas es propio de mi codigo. guardo el nombre, una descripcion y asocio a un articulo.

Espero que te sirva. Un saludo